# Management of directories and subrutines

Tags: batch, batch-file, working-directory

From the current directory %CD%, I need to go inside a subfolder and execute a subrutineA, then go back to the %CD% directory and go to the next subfolder and execute the same subrutineA, this process need to be done as many time as folders available.

The problem that I have is that I dont know how to define in a batch script the name of the subdirectory since this name it´s variable, and the amount of folders it´s also variable.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How’s this for a start:

> `@echo off`
>   `for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir/b/ad') do (`
>       `cd "%%D"`
>       *Do what you want to do.*
>       `cd ..`
>   `)`

Comment: Great, it help me a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

When you do not know what directory to return to and do not want to keep track of it, use `pushd` and `popd`.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir/b/ad') do (
    pushd "%%D"
    Do what you want to do.
    popd
)
```